# Using `URLProtocol` subclass for testing async/await URLSession calls

Tags: swift, async-await

I've only recently become aware of the technique of subclassing `URLProtocol` to enable testing of networking calls (previously I've used something akin to [Rob Napier's "Mockery of protocols"](https://robnapier.net/a-mockery-of-protocols))

Attempts to apply it to `async/await` calls results in a crash though. This code illustrates the problem - the completion-based test will pass, the async one will crash (e.g. `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1a587a0f0)`)

```
import XCTest
import Foundation

final class TestableNetworkingTests: XCTestCase {
    override func setUp() {
        URLProtocol.registerClass(StubUrlProtocol.self)
    }

    override class func tearDown() {
        URLProtocol.unregisterClass(StubUrlProtocol.self)
    }

    // URL doesn't matter - request never actually gets sent
    static let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://example.com/")!)

    func testCompletion() throws {
        StubUrlProtocol.observer = { request -> (URLResponse?, Data?) in
            return (nil, "Completion Hello".data(using: .utf8)!)
        }

        let responded = expectation(description: "Should have responded")

        var received: Data?

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: Self.request) { data, response, error in
            received = data
            responded.fulfill()
        }

        task.resume()

        wait(for: [responded], timeout: 5)

        let message = String(data: received ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8)

        XCTAssertEqual(message, "Completion Hello")
    }

    func testAsync() async throws {
        StubUrlProtocol.observer = { request -> (URLResponse?, Data?) in
            return (nil, "Awaited hello".data(using: .utf8)!)
        }

        // URLProtocol.registerClass makes this feel unnecessary,
        // but plenty of articles recommend setting .protocolClasses
        let cfg = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        cfg.protocolClasses = [StubUrlProtocol.self]
        let session = URLSession(configuration: cfg)

        let (received, _) = try await session.data(for: Self.request)
        let message = String(data: received, encoding: .utf8)
        XCTAssertEqual(message, "Awaited hello")
    }
}

class StubUrlProtocol: URLProtocol {
    static var observer: ((URLRequest) throws -> (URLResponse?, Data?))?

    override class func canInit(with request: URLRequest) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override class func canInit(with task: URLSessionTask) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override class func canonicalRequest(for request: URLRequest) -> URLRequest {
        request
    }

    override func startLoading() {
        do {
            guard let (response, data) = try Self.observer?(request) else {
                return
            }
            if let response {
                client?.urlProtocol(self, didReceive: response, cacheStoragePolicy: .notAllowed)
            }
            if let data {
                client?.urlProtocol(self, didLoad: data)
            }

            client?.urlProtocolDidFinishLoading(self)
        } catch {
            client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: error)
        }
    }

    override func stopLoading() { }
}
```

While the `Transport` approach gave us the option of making stubbed network calls completely synchronous, removing all need for any expectations, I am not sure that's going to be possible in an `async/await` world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom `URLProtocol` class, add the following line to your `startLoading` method:

```
self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didReceive: HTTPURLResponse(), cacheStoragePolicy: .allowed)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was mistakenly thinking it should be possible to not return a response for certain failure cases. Of course, that's what `didFailWithError:` is for...

Answer (score 1):

I also had same issues, first the control was not returning to URLSession data method, after implemented solution provided by @LondonGuy it started to return but the test was still crashing at teardown(after execution was complete), then I changed below setting and it started working.

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
```

I changed the URLSessionConfiguration to ephemeral from default.